# Debugging IMAP access of Yahoo in 2018

Tags: authentication, jakarta-mail, imap, yahoo

I am unable to authenticate IMAP with Yahoo and cannot pinpoint the cause. Can anyone help me to get more information other than the exception below?

"javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)"

Yahoo seems to have had many revisions to authentication over the years so that is why I put the current year in the title. Here is my setup:

On Yahoo: I have enabled less secure apps; I have checked and recheck credentials.

On my linux box: I have proven that IMAP works by using Thunderbird to connect and browse mail.

Here is the code:

```
  1  private static final String email_id = "xxxxxxxx@yahoo.com";
  2  private static final String password = {"xxxxxxxx"};
  3 
  4  public static void main(String[] args) {
  5  
  6    Properties properties = new Properties();
  7    //yahoo
  8    properties.put("mail.store.protocol",        "imap");
  9    properties.put("mail.imaps.host","imap.mail.yahoo.com");
 10    properties.put("mail.imaps.port",            "993");
 11    properties.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable",       "true");
 12    properties.put("mail.imap.mail.auth",        "true");
 13                          
 14    try {                 
 15       Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
 16       Store store     = session.getStore("imaps");
 17       
 18       store.connect(email_id, password);
 19       
 20       ...
 21       
 22       store.close();
 23    } catch (Exception e) {
 24       e.printStackTrace();
 25    }  
 26  } // end of main
 27 }
```

Comment: Did you create an app-specific password for Thunderbird?  You probably need to create one for your JavaMail app as well.

Comment: I did create an app specific password for JavaMail, but that didn't prove to be the answer. Thanks Bill

Answer (score 0):

Found the debugging answer. Included debugging on the Session object.

```
session.setDebug(true);
```

Comment: As described in the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).  Did that lead you to the answer for your problem?  If not, also try setting the [`mail.debug.auth`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/package-summary.html#mail.debug.auth) property to get additional detail in the debugging output.

Comment: Yes, it's working now. I looked at the methods available for Session and Store and found it. Thanks again Bill.

Comment: Right, but what caused the AuthenticationFailedException?  Were you using the wrong credentials, or was something else wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, can you tell us how you fixed it?