# Yahoomail Imap login in 2018

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm getting `AUTHENTICATE Invalid credentials` even though my username/ pass is correct. I did run into another post which another user was having the same issue, but no solution is posted, he has figured out how to solve it though according to the comments.

This is the link to the other post

[Debugging IMAP access of Yahoo in 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631965/debugging-imap-access-of-yahoo-in-2018)

Below is my log

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.0-b01
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "imap.mail.yahoo.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 ID MOVE NAMESPACE XYMHIGHESTMODSEQ UIDPLUS LITERAL+ CHILDREN SASL-IR AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XYMCOOKIEB64 AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=OAUTHBEARER] IMAP4rev1 Hello
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XYMCOOKIEB64
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: OAUTHBEARER
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=imap.mail.yahoo.com, user=myusername@ymail.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A0 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] AUTHENTICATE Invalid credentials
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] AUTHENTICATE Invalid credentials
```

and below is my code

```
public class Main {

    private static final String email_id = "myusername0@ymail.com";
    private static final String password = "mypassword";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        // yahoo
        properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
        properties.put("mail.imaps.host", "imap.mail.yahoo.com");
        properties.put("mail.imaps.port", "993");
        properties.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.imap.mail.auth", "true");

        try {
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
            session.setDebug(true);
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");

            store.connect(email_id, password);

            store.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // end of main

}
```

Anyone know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to [create an app-specific password for Yahoo Mail](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN15241.html).

Answer (score 1):

You currently do not have access to restricted scopes like mail. You will not be able to create an app with mail access and you will not be able to connect to IMAP via oauth2 until you go through the approval process.

Please read through https://developer.verizonmedia.com/mail/developer-access and if you want to proceed with the approval process you need to fill out the access request form you will find there.